# Excel - INDEX function for multiple columns of same value

Tags: excel, indexing, ms-office, match

I'm trying to put something together in excel that allows me to find the location of a lift at any time for a specific floor. A sample of the data is as follows:

```
Time     | Catering Area | Waste Area | Waste Area
5:00am   | L2            | L2         | L4
5:05am   | L2            | L7         | L5
5:10am   | B1            | L3         | L7
5:15am   | B2            | L4         | L9
```

I have set up two dropdown fields to select a level and area of the building (eg. L7 and Waste Area). Based on these these selections, I want to show when the lift is at the desired level within the area of the building; ie:

```
Level Selected: L7; Building Area Selected: Waste Area

Time     | Lift At L7?
5:00am   | No
5:05am   | Yes
5:10am   | Yes
5:15am   | No
```

I have set up an `INDEX` function, however I need to search across multiple columns with the same header name, ie. "Waste Area". The function so far is as follows:

```
INDEX($A$1:$D$5,MATCH(A10,A:A,0),[col_num])
```

This would then be paired with an `IF` statement to check whether the returned level matches the desired level from the dropdown field. The result will be a list of "Yes" or "No" for each time as shown above.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the COUNTIFS() worksheet function.

```
    =COUNTIFS(B$1:D$1,"Waste Area",B2:D2,"L7")
    =COUNTIFS(B$1:D$1,"Waste Area",B3:D3,"L7")
    =COUNTIFS(B$1:D$1,"Waste Area",B4:D4,"L7")
    =COUNTIFS(B$1:D$1,"Waste Area",B5:D5,"L7")
```

It will count the entries when the area matches and the floor matches.  Non-zero = "Yes".

Because your output time column has exactly the same is the input, I assume you don't actually need to search for the correct row.  **If you do** there are more tricks I can show you...

(edit...)
If you need to search for a specific time, replace the third argument `B2:D2` with a formula that finds the correct row.

```
    OFFSET(B$1:D$1,MATCH(A16,A$2:A$5),0)
```

So it becomes

```
    =COUNTIFS( B$1:D$1, AREA_NAME, OFFSET(B$1:D$1,MATCH(A16,A$2:A$5),0), FLOOR)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I do need to search for the correct row just based on the time. Each of the tables in my question are on different worksheets so the correct row will need to be found to populate the "Yes"/"No" table based on the time.

Comment: Edited to reflect your request.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your Data is in A1:D5 and that you have NAME'd your ranges  (note that Waste covers two columns)

```
Catering    =Sheet1!$B$2:$B$5
Times       =Sheet1!$A$2:$A$5
Waste       =Sheet1!$C$2:$D$5
```

Duplicate your list of Times in some cell; I used A11:A14

With your Dropdown values in the Area duplicating the defined Names, B9 containing the level selected, and D9 containing the Building area (both from the dropdown list), you can use the following formula to return TRUE or FALSE depending on if the lift is in position.

For Yes/No responses, use this formula as the Logical_test in an IF statement.

This formula must be **array-entered**, then fill down adjacent to each time:

```
=OR((A11=Times)*($B$9=INDIRECT($D$9)))
```

---

To **array-enter** a formula, after entering
the formula into the cell or formula bar, hold down
 while hitting .  If you did this
correctly, Excel will place braces {...} around the formula.